# Jest config (TypeScript): Type '{ __PATH_PREFIX__: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string | string[]'

Tags: typescript, jestjs, gatsby, ts-jest

I decided to write the Jest configuration for my Gatsby site using TypeScript with the `ts-jest/prests` package.

I'm getting a TypeScript error on the `globals` assignment in the code below:

```
import type { InitialOptionsTsJest } from 'ts-jest/dist/types'
import { jsWithBabel as tsjPreset } from 'ts-jest/presets'

const config: InitialOptionsTsJest = {
  transform: {
    ...tsjPreset.transform,
  },
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss)$': `identity-obj-proxy`,
    '.+\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$': `<rootDir>/__mocks__/file-mock.js`,
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules`, `\\.cache`, `<rootDir>.*/public`],
    transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!(gatsby)/)`],
    globals: {
      __PATH_PREFIX__: '',
    },
    testURL: `http://localhost`,
    setupFiles: [`<rootDir>/loadershim.js`],
  },
}

export default config
```

The error:

> Type '{ **PATH_PREFIX**: any; }' is not assignable to type 'string |
> string[]'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and
> '**PATH_PREFIX**' does not exist in type 'string[]'.ts(2322)
> Config.d.ts(135, 9): The expected type comes from this index
> signature.

I'm new to TypeScript, so I'm not exactly sure how to rectify this. The `globals` property with [`__PATH_PREFIX__` is needed by Gatsby for testing certain components](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/testing/unit-testing/).